# How to set the default font for a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, default

I want to be able to define a font family for my WPF application. Preferably using a resource dictionary as a theme referenced from `App.xaml`. I've tried creating a `Style` as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />            
</Style>
```

But this doesn't work. Setting the type to `TextBlock` works for most controls but there are a few controls where this doesn't apply.

I know you can set the font on a window and have all child controls of that window inherit the font. But I think any dialog windows will go back to the default font, which is not exactly what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 68):

Assuming your `Window` subclasses don't override `DefaultStyleKey`, you can simply add it to your Window style, since `TextElement.FontFamilyProperty` is an inherited property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />             
</Style>
```

You also need to add the following to your App constructor after the `InitializeComponent` call:

```
FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
{
    DefaultValue = FindResource(typeof(Window))
});
```

How it works:  After the App object finishes initializing, the Window style specified therein is made the default style for all windows.

Comment: This does not work because the Style is not applied to types that are inherited form Window.

Comment: @Matze:  It works for me. Perhaps you accidentally overrode DefaultStyleKey or explicitly set a window style?

Comment: @Ray: Your snippet definitely does not work. Because you have to use a class derived from Window, some additional code and/or xal is involved.

Comment: @Matze: Try it, it works! Do this: 1. Create a new WPF Application in Visual Studio. 2. Add the code above to your Application.Resources. 3. Add a Button to Window1 with text content. 4. Run. You will see the font has changed (this is more obvious if you use Value="Times New Roman"). 5. Add window Window2 with another Button. 6. Add "new Window2().Show()" to Window1's constructor. 7. Run again. You will see that both windows pick up the new font. 8. Figure out what's different between your code and this simple example you'll know where you're going wrong.

Comment: @Ray: Does not work. Just created the example as you suggested. The Style is only applied to the designer view. Maybe you something like 
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">

Comment: @Matze: This was very puzzling because what I wrote in my answer is *exactly* the code I use in my production applications. I finally figured out why it worked for me but not for you and have updated my answer to correct the problem. Thank you very much for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Or inside the    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) of your Application class. Because you need to create your own Main method to directly call InitializeComponent of App. Thanks for your efforts to help!

Comment: Actually I don't have my own Main method.  I simply do it in the App object's constructor.  All I write is `public App() { InitializeComponent(); FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(...); }`.  This seems cleaner to me than putting it in OnStartup.

Comment: This method is not working for me.  I'm not sure why InitializeComponent() is here - the Application class doesn't have that method.  In case App is supposed to be a form class, I tried that, which also didn't work

Comment: @Kieren:  When you create a WPF project using Visual Studio it creates an App.xaml.cs and an App.xaml.  The App class in App.xaml.cs is a partial class, and App.xaml adds an InitializeComponent() method to it.  If your compiler is telling you your App class don't have an InitializeComponent(), check that your App.xaml has the right x:Class, including the right NET Framework namespace.  If your application is structured differently, you can add this code somewhere else in your application startup.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I put `Style = (Style)FindResource(typeof(Window));` right after the InitializeComponent() call instead and that worked for me. Thanks goes to http://avolk.parivedasolutions.com/2011/03/default-wpf-application-font.html

Comment: But it doesn't affect TextBox, so what to do about it?

Comment: This is the correct solution but don't put it into the App constructor. Its place is in the App's `Startup` handler. You might also want to create additional similar styles, not just for `Window`, and call the accordingly (eg. for menus).

Answer (score 30):

Most of proposed solutions didn't work for me. My simple solution:

Add this to App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="14" />
</Style>
```

Add this in your MainWindow constructor (after InitializeComponent):

```
Style = (Style)FindResource(typeof(Window));
```

Answer (score 23):

**Actually you can get a full XAML solution combining some of the other answers here.**

If your main window is called `WinMain` (the one you load before all others), just add a reference to a style named e.g. `WinAll`

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.WinMain"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WinMain" Height="450" Width="800"
    Style="{StaticResource WinAll}">
```

and then define your style this way

```
<Style x:Key="WinAll" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
        Value="Comic Sans MS" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
        Value="14" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It may look not elegant for the first glace, it's the best way for vs2015+.net framework 4.5.2, out of every answers I found.

Comment: I find this to be the most elegant version. When using the hot reload feature if the answer from Jowen is used it can't be hot reloaded. However with this answer it is easily possible to hot reload since it just is treated as a normal style.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful, the Style just needs to be in App.xaml.

Answer (score 17):

One simple way to do it programmatically:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me, with XAML from Rays answer (to get both editor view and runtime font correct)

Answer (score 10):

I found this :

```
TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
typeof(TextElement),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS")));

TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
typeof(TextBlock),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple workaround in the `App.xaml` (no code behind needed):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForeBrush" Color="Blue" />

<Style x:Key="GenericTextStyle">
    <!-- Generic control forecolor definition -->
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForeBrush}" />

    <!-- Add a definition for each unworking nested control -->
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForeBrush}" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Just bind your windows style to this. Works perfectly for me. Only some properties need to be defined in the nested tree. For example the property `FontSize` can be specify only in the generic section.

I don't know why is necessary to do this trick. It's strange because Label should be derived from Control. Anyone have any idea about it?