# Binding a static resource to an existing value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to simplify bindings in WPF. Say, I'm creating a `FontFamily` resource in App.xaml which binds to a string value in the application settings, to avoid a long line of binding expression in every window. But I found that I couldn't find a way to do that.

It is said that there's a `x:Arguments` in XAML 2009, but that does not apply here.

My approaches:

```
<DynamicResource x:Key="PrimaryFont" ResourceKey="{Binding PrimaryFont, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Converter={StaticResource StringToFontFamilyConverter}}"/>
```

failed, throwing an `XamlParseException`.

```
<FontFamily x:Key="PrimaryFont">
    <Binding Path="PrimaryFont" Source="{x:Static properties:Settings.Default}" Converter="{StaticResource StringToFontFamilyConverter}"/>
</FontFamily>
```

this even does not compile.

I don't want to add that in code behind, because I don't want to make everything look like a mess. Is that possible?

EDIT: this is not a duplicate of [Setting global font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615672/setting-global-font-family). The `FontFamily` is just for explaining purpose, in real world there will be more than one kind of element I want to simplify the binding on, and the element might not be a good target for a new style.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of that?

Comment: There is no need for a converter and therefore, the Binding part is relatively small: ``FontFamily="{Binding MyFont, Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}}"``, assuming that there is ``string`` named ``MyFont`` in ``Settings.Default``. Also, I used ``p`` instead of ``properties`` to make it smaller.

Comment: @Ron thanks. I'll use that on the appliable settings for now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I found an interesting solution in the process of dealing with another problem.

This awesome little proxy class mentioned in [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) written by [@ThomasLevesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) is my life saver:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And thanks to [@mkoertgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592915/mkoertgen) for sharing that find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24227295/6395553).