# TextBox set default font

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textbox, code-behind

How can I set default font for `TextBox`?

For `TextBlock` it's (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8433204/1997232)):

```
TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlock),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Verdana")));
```

Trying to do the same for `TextBox`:

```
TextBox.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Verdana")));
```

will throw:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' threw an exception. PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'TextBox'.

---

Here is repro:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="123123" />
    <TextBox Text="123123" BorderThickness="0" Padding="-2,0,-2,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Setting `TextBlock` font as above in window constructor (before `InitializeComponent()`) works. How to set `TextBox` default font (it's Segoe by default to me)? I need a solution to set it in as `"Verdana"` in one place for a whole application.

---

Intellisense shows:

[image: TextBlock]

[image: TextBox]

Comment: Calling OverrideMetadata for a type of the framework (e.g. TextBlock) is dubious anyway. You should set default values by Styles.

Comment: I tried setting `TextElement` it doesn't work for anything. Setting `TextBlock` one works, but only for `TextBlock`.

Comment: Have you tried `OverrideMetadata(Type, PropertyMetadata, DependencyPropertyKey)` version with `DependencyPropertyKey`

Comment: @bars222, no idea what you mean. Can you write a complete line of code?

Comment: @Clemens, how do I set style which applies to either (`TextBox` or `TextBlock`) same font? See [@Kiel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36403596/1997232), it works, but only for one (never for both). They have `FrameworkElement` base class, but it doesn't contains `FontFamilyProperty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `TextBox` to `TextBoxBase`. Somehow it worked for me.

```
TextBoxBase.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( TextBoxBase ),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( new FontFamily( "Verdana" ) ) );
```

Comment: VS15 suggest to use `Control. ... typeof(TextBoxBase)`. Strangely enough that combo works (and I like it more than `app.xaml` solution), thanks a lot, wouldn't guess myself ever.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the way to changing fonts in app (for useful question).

Answer (score 1):

For your entire application, you can set it in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

For individual files, you can set this in the XAML after your Window or UserResource opening tag:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Or if it's a 'UserControl', replace 'Window' with 'UserControl' - you get the idea.

Your basic format would look like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="123123" />
            <TextBox Text="123123" BorderThickness="0" Padding="-2,0,-2,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I have 20 windows and 50 user controls, it would be good to set defaults in one place. Your example works **only** for `TextBlock` (`TextBox` font style is still "Segoe"). I can change `TargetType` to `TextBox` and then it will only work for `TextBox`. Setting both seem to only apply style to the first defined one. Funny.

Comment: @Sinatr - you could set it globally in App.xaml.

Comment: Also, the FontSize aimed at TextBlock also affects Buttons (at runtime, not in Studio)...?!?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is not setting `TextBox` style alone (sorry for a missleading tittle), but setting it together with `TextBlock`.

Problem seems related to that those controls don't have common base class to inherit `FontFamilyProperty` from. `TextBox` takes one from `TextBoxBase` and `TextBlock` from itself. Attempting to set both in either code behind (of window) or window xaml will lead to either exception or nothing (won't work for both).

The *trick* is to set it in application resources, don't ask me why, but it works then (and works for everything):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    </Style>
    <!-- not sure if this make sense -->
    <Style TargetType="TextElement">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Following also works (thanks to [@bars222's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36404187/1997232)):

```
// font overrides
TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Verdana")));
TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlock),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Verdana")));
Control.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBoxBase),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Verdana")));
```