# Set font family for every page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set my font family for all my pages...

In my MainWindow which contains the frame for the page, I have the following:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Fonts/Gotham Rounded Light.OTF#Gotham Rounded Light" />
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
<Window.Triggers>
```

And in my MainWindow code behind I have this:

```
Style = (Style)FindResource(typeof(Window));
```

The page font still doesn't change though.... any idea what I could be doing wrong? I'm not sure how the main window will reflect it's style on all the pages created

Code behind of the App.xaml

```
using Engine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace V
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        Window mainWindow = null;
        string dllToLoad = null;

        App()
        {
            Startup += App_Startup;
        }

        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ReadJson();

                Window wnd = LoadRunTimeDLL();
                wnd.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                wnd.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to load window from{0} - {1}", "OtherWindow", ex.Message));
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to load window from{0} - {1}", "OtherWindow", ex.Message), ex);
            }
        }

        private void ReadJson()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("../../Config/Config.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

                dllToLoad = jsonData.DllToLoad;
            }
        }

        private Window LoadRunTimeDLL()
        {
            string assemblyName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.dll",
                new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName, dllToLoad);

            if (assemblyName != null)
            {
                Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
                Type[] tlist = asm.GetTypes();
                foreach (Type t in tlist)
                {
                    if (t.Name == "MainWindow")
                    {
                        mainWindow = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Window;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return mainWindow;
        }
    }
}
```

And the App.XAML

```
<Application x:Class="V.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:V" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
</Application>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the default font for a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145511/how-to-set-the-default-font-for-a-wpf-application)

Comment: Edney i've already read that but it doesn't work. The page doesn't not have all of it's elements set to that font.

Comment: Can we see the your App.xaml

Comment: posted, just updated it

Comment: That is the App.xaml.cs file. Please post the App,xam file. It will stat with something like <Application x:Class="V.App"

Comment: sorry edney let me do that now

Comment: done - check it now

Answer (score 0):

A `Window` style doesn't apply to `Pages` in a `Frame`. Try to define an implicit `Page` style in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="V.App"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:V"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            d1p1:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman" />
    </Style>
</Application>
```