# WPF global style for Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a global style (Font size and Font family) into my WPF application for Window I have, but no style Is applied to It, whatever I do. I think my problem Is that my startup Window Is not App.xaml, because I use App.xaml just to check If user has permission to run application. But right after that my desired Window opens, so **StartupUri** in my **App.xaml** Is set to that Window.

Here is my `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             StartupUri="FirstWindowToShow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>

        <!--Style that should be applied to all Windows-->
        <Style x:Key="Win_style" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        </Style>

        <!--Style for all Pages - works fine-->
        <Style x:Key="PageFont" TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

And here is my `FirstWindowToShow.xaml` :

```
   <Window x:Class="MyApp.FirstWindowToShow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Priprava_Podatkov"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Some title" Height="480" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Background="#FFF9F9F9" OpacityMask="Black">

    <Grid>

        <Menu x:Name="G_Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="792">
            <MenuItem x:Name="Menu_Program">
                <MenuItem x:Name="Menu_V" Header="About" Click="Menu_V_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="Menu_End" Header="Close" Click="Menu_End_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Department 1" Height="20" Width="148">
                <MenuItem x:Name="Dept_1" Header="Custom controlling" Click="Dept_1_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Frame x:Name="Frame_s" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>

        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,386,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Transparent">
            <StatusBarItem Width="73">
                <Label Content="User:" FontWeight="Bold" Width="73"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Label x:Name="LblU" Content="user" FontWeight="Light"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" Height="10" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Label Content="User permissions:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Label x:Name="LblN" Content="Rights" FontWeight="Light"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem >

                <Label x:Name="Lbl_P" Content="Data exported..." >
                    <Label.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimacija">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </Style.Resources>

                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= Progress_DoKonca, Path= IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimacija}" />
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="flash"/>
                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                </DataTrigger>

                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Label.Style>
                </Label>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-10,0,10,0">
                <Grid>
                    <ProgressBar x:Name="Progress_TillEnd" Width="150" Height="20" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Progress_Txt" Text="{Binding ElementName=Progress_DoKonca, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have been trying all sorts of things in code or XAML, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145511/how-to-set-the-default-font-for-a-wpf-application) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml), but still with no success. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: When you say 'no style is applied', do your existing controls have default font e.g. Arial? Or the control text is not visible? Can you remove the Foreground="{x:Null}" from the FirstWindowToShow and try?

Comment: @Insane, I posted full Window code since It's not that long. I have been trying to delete everything I came up with, but desired font just Isn't showing inside Window. I have tried **Foreground="{x:Null}"** too.

Comment: Looks like StatusBar and Menu are causing me problems. Everything Is fine If I set their styles manually. Strangely style for Pages work, but I have no StatusBar or Menu there,

Comment: Each window you have is not typed as a window. It is a MainWindow or a Window1 or whatever. Hence your style will target none. Simplest approach is to give the style a key and explicitly reference it in each window.

Comment: @Andy, how do you mean that ? My FirstWindowToShow inhertis from Wind class. I tried even **<Style x:Key="Win_style" TargetType="local:FirstWindowToShow">**.

Comment: @Lucy82, Try to reference to properties ot the parent window like: `<StatusBar FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=_FirstWindow_, Path=FontFamily}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=_FirstWindow_, Path=FontSize}"`...

Comment: I mean give it a key foo and use style=dynamicresource foo in the window. You will need your style to use basedon to reference the base style for a window. Having said that. You only have 2 setters. If that's all you're using then just paste the two lines into your windows.

Comment: Or you could use the approach in answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145511/how-to-set-the-default-font-for-a-wpf-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the controls like Menu and StatusBar it is necessary to set the style explicitly like below:

```
<Style  x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />   
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />        
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />        
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Window1}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
```

Comment: that is what I figured out too. But guys say that their solution work too. So I have to recreate project to confirm that.

Comment: @Lucy, I tried create project from scratch but this does not worked for me. I hope will work for you!

Comment: you mean solution from Andrew and mm8 ? mm8 stated that It worked for him.

Comment: I think you are right. I have come to same conclusion before you but I marked your answer, thanks for all effort. Maybe there Is a way to do this even with these controls, but I'm sure It's not easy :)

Comment: @Lucy82, I'm glad this solution works for you. There are some additional comments in the following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162456/the-ability-to-propagate-default-values-down-the-element-tree-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162456/the-ability-to-propagate-default-values-down-the-element-tree-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 4):

This is what I've done in the past, so see if it works for you:

In your App.xaml, remove the `x:Key` from the Window style, so it becomes:

```
    <!--Style that should be applied to all Windows-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>
```

Then in your App.xaml.cs (code-behind), override the `OnStartup` method and add this code:-

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
        {
            DefaultValue = FindResource(typeof(Window))
        });
    }
```

This will apply those styles in the App.xaml `Window` style (i.e. FontFamily and FontStyle) to all windows created by the application.

Comment: that doesn't work for me either. I think I will need to recreate project, something Is wrong. Could maybe a cause of all problem be a fact that I created a folder "WINDOW" and put both files there - App.xaml & FirstWindowToShow.xaml, Is WPF very sensitive about moving files ?

Answer (score 0):

Why would a `Style` with an `x:Key` of "Win_style" be applied to all windows?

You could keep `Win_style` and define an implict `Style` per window type (e.g. `FirstWindowToShow`) that is based on `Win_style`:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <!--Style that should be applied to all Windows-->
    <Style x:Key="Win_style" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>

    <!-- implicit window styles, one for each window -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FirstWindowToShow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Win_style}" />

    <!--Style for all Pages - works fine-->
    <Style x:Key="PageFont" TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Create a new WPF application using the defailt template, copy the sample markup from answer into `App.xaml`and replace `FirstWindowToShow` with `MainWindow` and you'll see that it works.

Comment: yes that will be my next step, looks like something is wrong with my project, no solutions work for me. Must have been something that I did in past.

Comment: confirmed that It doesn't work even in new WPF project, you didn't try It on xaml markup that I posted. Correct answer Is what Jackdaw posted.

Comment: @Lucy82: Your question doesn't mention anything about some `Menu` and `StatusBar`, does it? This does certainly work to solve the issue of applying a style to a window.

Comment: @Yes It doesn't, because we didn't know that those controls were causing a problem. However I posted a whole xaml of Window, and that Is how we figured It out.